# SwiftUI Deep link for a destination within app?

Tags: swiftui, navigation, uikit

I figured out Android has a deep link for a specific destination within app.
(https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link). However, I don't know how to implement this with SwiftUI which is limited to NavigationView/NavigationLink.

For Example, when tapped a banner it directly goes to Event Tab and a specific event page which is a WebView.

[image]

If there is no way to implement it with SwiftUI, I even want to know the way with UIKit.
Thanks.

Comment: There is, look at the “Widget Code Along” from WWDC 21 they do just this, it’s only glossed over in the videos but the code samples give you all you need

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.handlesExternalEvents(preferring:allowing:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/path/handlesexternalevents(preferring:allowing:)) and [`onOpenURL(perform:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/SwiftUI/View/onOpenURL(perform:)) as follows:

```
@main
struct DeepLinkApp: App {    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
            .handlesExternalEvents(preferring: ["scheme"], allowing: ["scheme"])
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

        }
        .onOpenURL{ url in
            // set state from the url
        }
    }
}
```